# Check that write()/send() can process whole buffer without block, fail otherwise (no partial write)

Tags: c++, send, nonblocking

I am using SOCK_SEQPACKET connection, and it is critical for me to ensure that whole buffer is sent with single write()/send() call. I am also operating with device driver that is designed to handle a complete block of data with single call. At the same time I want to handle the situation when write()/send() blocks due to buffer overflow, i.e. I want to have a feedback whether current implementation gets a bottleneck here. I'm working with glibc, Linux 2.6.

I need to implement a method that accepts a buffer, and it either sends a buffer completely or indicates a failure due to blocking (i.e. system buffer overflow).

It looks like using send(..., MSG_DONTWAIT)/fcntl(..., O_NONBLOCK) is not a solution as they accept partial write prior to reporting EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN. Is there a way to check whether there is enough space in outgoing buffer or is there a dedicated write-complete-or-fail method?

Alternatively, is it possible to detect block by other means? For example, timer+signal seems to be an option, but I do not like the idea to set it for each write.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which domain/protocol is used? PF_INET and SCTP?

Comment: Unix socket: fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0);

Comment: Are you sure that non-blocking SOCK_SEQPACKET unix socket allows a partial send? I have used Unix datagram socket (AF_UNIX+SOCK_DGRAM). `sendto(,,MSG_DONTWAIT,,)` call of it will fail with errno EAGAIN or EMSGSIZE if you try to send too big message. And the reveicer will never reveive a partial datagram.

Comment: So far so good, it seems that AF_UNIX+SOCK_SEQPACKET does not allow partial sends, and it returns EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK as expected. I am not sure whether it is a universal behavior. Thank you for a hint, I was confused by 'man' page that partial sens occurs nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

Experiment reveals that no partial send occurs on my setup (glibc 2.11.1, kernel 2.6.32-29) and that EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK is returned by send(...MSG_DONTWAIT) as expected for AF_UNIX+SOL_SEQPACKET socket.

Not sure whether behavior is universal.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the value of SO_SNDLOWAT on the socket will give you a clue as to the sizes of messages that can be sent without risking partial sends.

Comment: Are you sure? 
man says:
'Specify the minimum number of bytes in the buffer until the socket layer will pass the data to the protocol (SO_SNDLOWAT) ... These two (+RCVLOWAT) values are initialized to 1.  SO_SNDLOWAT is not changeable on Linux.'

Comment: It depends on the implementation; one use of SO_SNDLOWAT is to define the minimum the buffer space available before select() will flag the socket fd as ready for writing. So messages of that size (or smaller) will be passed to the protocol complete. But if it's fixed at 1 then I agree it's not useful...