# Linux: send whole message or none of it on TCP socket

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, buffer, send

I'm sending various custom message structures down a nonblocking TCP socket. I want to send either the whole structure in one send() call, or return an error with no bytes sent if there's only room in the send buffer for part of the message (ie send() returns EWOULDBLOCK). If there's not enought room, I will throw away the whole structure and report overflow, but I want to be recoverable after that, ie the receiver only ever receives a sequence of valid complete structures. Is there a way of either checking the send buffer free space, or telling the send() call to do as described? Datagram-based sockets aren't an option, must be connection-based TCP. Thanks.

Comment: In short: no. Even if you are able to send it in one piece, there is no guarantee that the receiver receives it in one piece. (there is not even a guarantee that he gets it at all)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check that write()/send() can process whole buffer without block, fail otherwise (no partial write)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788152/check-that-write-send-can-process-whole-buffer-without-block-fail-otherwise) (Looks like the answer is that `SOCK_SEQPACKET` _might_ do what you want on Linux, but I can find no evidence that this is guaranteed by POSIX)

Comment: wildplasser is correct, but...  If you your messages are smaller than the Path MTU you can get what you want the vast majority of the time.  However. based on my experience anyway, you cannot rely on the PMTU to stay unchanged on the public internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP has no support for transactions; this is something which you must handle on [layer 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_7%3a_application_layer) (application).

Answer (score 4):

Linux provides a `SIOCOUTQ` ioctl() to query how much data is in the TCP output buffer:

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/tcp.7.html

You can use that, plus the value of `SO_SNDBUF`, to determine whether the outgoing buffer has enough space for any particular message.  So strictly speaking, the answer to your question is "yes".

But there are two problems with this approach.  First, it is Linux-specific. Second, what are you planning to do when there is not enough space to send your whole message?  Loop and call `select` again?  But that will just tell you the socket is ready for writing again, causing you to busy-loop.

For efficiency's sake, you should probably bite the bullet and just deal with partial writes; let the network stack worry about breaking your stream up into packets for optimal throughput.

Comment: If the whole message can't be sent it is discarded. This is fine for the use-case. Lost messages are allowable, but it is critical that a client never receives part of a message followed by the start of another one. I will probably have to implement an additional app-level buffer on the sending side. Was just hoping to avoid that.

Comment: @gimmeamilk reading your comment make me think you're mis understanding how TCP work ... it's not about datagram, it's a stream: the client will not receive partial message if you write it fully (and don't suffer from connection loss)